# permission error on saving .java file

Tags: java, linux, unix, permissions, linux-mint

I installed JDK on my linux mint to learn programming java. One problem I have is the permission error when saving a ".java" file into my Documents folder or any other folder.
When I write a program and try to save it as a ".java" file before compiling, I get an error
 `permission denied. The file on disk may now be truncated!`
why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening?

I have tried saving  into different folders but nothing works. Although I have found that I can save it when I use root permission. The problem with using root, is that I can't compile the file as another error will arise. I later found that I can only compile as user.
How can I stop from going back and forth as root and user?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al ~/Documents` ?

Answer (score 1):

can you save any other file in your Documents folder? most likely it has nothing to do with file being *.java. If somehow it's a file system issue, then any file should manifest the same problem. So try saving to any other folder inside your /home/[your username] directory (where you normally have full permissions).

quick googling for this error message seems to indicate a permission problem with your home folder:

http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=317617

so make sure to try other folders, or just the /home/[username]
and if it's the same issue, that link should help

Comment: well i can save other documents or file into the folder though. so its the folder issue..

Comment: have you tried following the example at the link? Basically, use sudo to fix the folder permissions. The first comment to your post asks you to provide what is the current permission set to - chances are, all you need to do is something with 'sudo chmod ...' or 'sudo chown ...'